# Twitter search API VS Operators

Tags: api, search, twitter

I've found this page about the Twitter search API and some operators :
http://search.twitter.com/operators

But is it possible to make a search like :
All posts containing the words "ipod OR ipad" AND all posts containing the words "funny OR joke" **in just one query** ?

Like : "happy AND hour" OR "ipod AND ipad" **(in the same query)**

In a search string, it would be something like : 
"fun+sexy"+OR+"joke+sexy"

BUT, this string in the API returns ONLY posts with the two words together, I would like to have the posts that contins "fun AND sexy", but not necessarily the two words together.

example : It returns posts like : "this is fun sexy cool" (somehow twitter ignores commas)
and doesn't returns posts like : "this is fun, cool and sexy"

This doesn't look like it's possible (in the same query). Of course, you can do it with 2 different queries ;) . I think it's the only way.

Comment: Why vote down? I think it is a design flaw of twitter api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do this:

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=funny+OR+joke

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=iPod+AND+iPad

http://search.twitter.com/search?q="happy+hour"

**Update** http://search.twitter.com/search?q="fun+sexy"+OR+"joke+sexy"

The API clearly says that. If you want results having "Happy hour" (text after another), surround it with double quote (")

Comment: I upadated my post, it wasn't clear I guess. I want to do this, but inside the same query.

Comment: It would not find the post : "blabla fun blabla blabla sexy"
It just finds the posts like : "blabla blabla fun sexy blabla blabla"
subtle difference :|

Answer (score 0):

Have you **tried**?

I get different results from "ipad AND iphone" than I do from "ipad OR iphone", and the "AND" query only gives me ones with both, so it appears to work just fine.

It looks like "AND" is unnecessary, as terms are ANDed by default.

Comment: Yes, I tried. With only just one query it doesn't seems to be possible. Of course if you make it with 2 different query it's easy.